# Laravel - How to maintain my project on server using github

Tags: php, laravel, github

How to upload my project to server , migrate my database , and edit my project using github or any other way .

i tried this way and it seems to be very stupid.

i uploaded myproject.zip and extracted .
then created database and imported a backup from my localhost database.

suggest any helpful easier way to do it .
thanks.

Comment: and my edits is going in stupid way . i edit on localhost , then i re-upload my_project.zip again and re-extract it :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) is something for you.

You can use git-ftp for script based projects like PHP.
Most of the low-cost web hosting companies do not provide SSH or git support, but only FTP.

Git-ftp provides an easy way to deploy git tracked projects. Instead of transferring the whole project, it only transfers the files that changed since the last time.

Even if you are playing with different branches, git-ftp knows which files are different. No ordinary FTP client can do that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a repository on github. And then on your local computer initialize git if you are on Linux (ubuntu to be precise) navigate to your project folder and run

```
git init
```

it will show an output about initialized a working directory or something like that. Navigate to .git folder and edit config file with your favorite editor, the content looks like the following

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://your-username@github.com/your-user-name/your-repository.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

after modifying this file navigate back to your project root folder and run

```
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'
git push origin master
```

now login to your server via putty or any ssh client you use navigate to your project root folder initialize git by

```
git init
```

navigate to .git folder and edit the config file paste the same code you pasted on your local machine and then navigate back to your project root folder(on server) run

```
git pull origin master
```

You are in sync now. No anytime you make any changes to your localhost you should perform following commands from your project root folder

```
git add .
git commit -m 'any custom message about these changes'
git push origin master
```

and from your server

```
git pull origin master
```

Never make any changes on your development server in ANY CASE. you should add the files you want to ignore while upload and download in the .gitignore file under your project root in your localhost. e.g to exclude a folder from uploaded add following in your .gitignore file

```
/foldername/*
```